# График в Excel. Помогите составить

Tags: excel

Добрый день!!

Допустим у меня есть такая таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И мне исходя их этих данных нужно составить такую диаграмму;
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю понятно что для каждого игрока есть своя линия, в каждый период она занимает определенное состояние. Это нужно отобразить на графике.
Игроков может быть до 10 человек. Периодов неограничено. 
Сотрировка идет такая: Период, Игрок.

Comment: А таблицу менять нельзя? Я пока что вижу простой выход: сделать всего 3 строки (по строке на период), и в каждой строке сделать по 3 игрока с его состояниями. Ну или формировать такую таблицу макросом, а по ней уже строить диаграмму.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно это делается сводной диаграммой(таблицей). Поля осей, легенды - можно просто таскать мышкой меняя местам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]